# What kind of things will call an application error in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am looking at error handling. I found the following code:

```
  protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = this.Server.GetLastError();

        this.Response.Clear();
        this.Server.ClearError();

        var errorRoute = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
        var tenant = errorRoute.Values["tenant"].ToString();

        var route = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "controller", "Error" },
            { "action", "Index" },
            { "tenant", tenant }
        };

        if (exception != null)
        {
            route.Add("message", exception.Message);
        }

        this.Response.RedirectToRoute(route);
    }
```

But what can cause an application_error? Would this be something user generated like when there is a duplicate entry in the database or is it just for some kind of system exception?

Comment: If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 4):

@cebirci answered your question. However, I would strongly discourage you from using `Application_Error` in MVC since there are built in ways in MVC to handle errors.

First of all, you got `[HandleError]` attribute which you can decorate your controllers and/or actions with. It will render the view `Shared\Error.cshtml` each time an unhandled exception is caught.

The problem with `[HandleError]` is that it can't take care of Not Found (404). To handle 404 you need to create an error controller and configure customErrors in web.config.

I describe it more in detail in [my blog](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 3):

`Application_Error` method handles all exceptions your application throws. If you want to handle a custom situation like duplicate entry, you can throw an exception like this:

```
if(entriesDuplicated)
{
   throw new Exception("The message that describes the error");
}
```

It will be handled in `Application_Error` method.